# Pause the run method of a QThread to test it

Tags: python, pyqt, python-requests, qthread

I create a Worker object like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtSql, QtCore
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession


class Worker(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self):

        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

        self.exiting = False
        self.list_urls = # Urls coming from somewhere

        # List to store the urls of the pages to request
        self.list_futures_urls = []


    def __del__(self):

        """Method to destroy the thread properly"""

        self.exiting = True
        self.wait()


    def run(self):

        """Main function. Starts the real business"""
        print(self.exiting) # -> True !!!!!

        session = FuturesSession(max_workers=10)

        for url in self.list_urls:

            future = session.get(url)
            future.add_done_callback(completeData)
            self.list_futures_urls.append(future)

        # HERE !!!!! WHY ?
        print(self.exiting) # -> True
        self.exiting = False
        print(self.exiting) # -> False

        while not self.exiting:
            self.sleep(20000)
            # self.wait()


    def completeData(self):

        total_futures = self.list_futures_urls

        # Checking if all the futures have started and finished
        if len(total_futures) !=  len(self.list_urls):
            return
        else:
            states_futures = []
            for result in total_futures:
                states_futures.append(result.done())

            if False not in states_futures:
                self.exiting = True
                print("boum")
```

As you can see, my worker is a thread, and starts an asynchronous requests Session. So the run() method starts the asynchronous web requests, and then is done. At this stage, the thread normally sends a "finished" signal. But the asynchronous web requests are of course not done.

What can I do to block the "finished" signal, until all the asynchronous web requests are done ?

I tried with wait() at the end of the run() method, but I get:

```
QThread::wait: Thread tried to wait on itself
```

I also tried with sleep(), but no result, the 'finished' signal is still emitted.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce that, but I have some annotations that might help:

What can be happening is all asynchronous tasks get done before the interpreter reach the line:

```
 while not self.exiting:
```

You're assuming that the asynchornous calls will give you enough time to reach the `while` statement before all processing get done.

On the other hand since you're using `QtCore.QThread` you don't need a control variable for knowing when to stop, you can just stop the thread using one of these: [QThread.exit](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthread.html#exit), [QThread.quit](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthread.html#quit) or [QThread.terminate](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthread.html#terminate), be aware the last it's not recomended.

About `self.exiting` becoming `True`, Its very rare, I have to say, but there is no way this can happend (looking at your code) without executing the line `self.exiting = True` I suggest set a breakpoint there and look the callstack for trace the path of calls that cause that line get executed.

Another idea is set a [Hardware Breakpoit](http://Debugger%20flow%20control:%20Hardware%20breakpoints%20vs%20software%20breakpoints) to see when the value of `self.exiting` get changed.

**Posible Solution:**

```
class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    # I don't test this code, is just for show
    # the way to go.

    def __init__(self):

        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.list_urls = # Urls coming from somewhere
        self.list_futures_urls = []

    def run(self):

        """Main function. Starts the real business"""
        session = FuturesSession(max_workers=10)

        for url in self.list_urls:
            future = session.get(url)
            future.add_done_callback()
            self.list_futures_urls.append(future)

        while (True):
            # You could add some sleep here in order to create a small delay between iterations.
            # WARNING: You have to aware of the posibility that a result.get() call never returns True,
            #          in that this code (as well as yours) will run into an infinite loop/thread.
            results = [result.done() for result in  self.list_futures_urls]
            if (False not in results):
                self.exit()

        # Callback removed from this code since the only purpose of 
        # it was to end the thread when all task get done.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. In the __init__ function, self.exiting is set to False. So it should loop, and it does. If I remove the while loop, and don't have the message "QThread::wait: Thread tried to wait on itself"

Comment: Actually, you were kind of right, but it's understandable. self.exiting is True at the end of run(). I editing my question, could you have a look ? I really don't understand what's going on.

Comment: @Rififi, I could not reproduce what's happening to you, but I have edited the answer, and wrote some things that might be helpful.